# Extension of the IVP $y'(x)=y(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}-1)+e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that the IVP $y'(x)=y(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}-1)+e^x$ , $y(1)=y_0$ has a solution that is extandable on $[1,\infty)$?

I tried to bound the solution of the IVP  in order to show that there exists a solution that can be bounded in any open interval but failed to do so. Started by

$|\dot{y}|=|y(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}-1)+e^x|\leq|y(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}-1)|+e^x\leq|y(x)|+e^x$ and got stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
y(x) = y_0 +\int^x_1 y(s)\sin\left(\frac{1}{s}-1\right)\ ds+ e^x-e
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
|y(x)| \leq |y_0-e| +e^x + \int^x_1|y(s)|\ ds.
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
F'(x)-F(x) \le C + e^x
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int^x_1|y(s)|\ ds.
\end{align}
In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(F(x)e^{-x}) \le Ce^{-x}+1 \ \ \implies \ \ F(x)e^{-x} \le F(1)e^{-1}+C\int^x_1e^{-s}\ ds+x.
\end{align}
In short, you will have $F(x) \leq Ae^x+Bxe^x+C$ which means $|y(x)| \leq A'e^x+B'xe^x+C'$.